# Laravel5.1 Logout when browser is close using javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

How to detect that browser is close using javascript. I have not found any solutions using laravel. So now I am using jquery ajax request to logout before window is close. For this I am using-

```
function windowUnloaded() {

    var unloaded = false;
    $(window).on('beforeunload', unload);
    function unload(){      
        if(!unloaded){
            $('body').css('cursor','wait');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                async: false,
                url: '/logout',
                success:function(){ 
                    unloaded = true; 
                    $('body').css('cursor','default');
                },
                timeout: 5000
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This works only when I refresh page. But I want it when browser is close. Somebody can tell me from where I am wrong or If there is any other better solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to logout the user as and when the browser is closed? Why don't you set `expire_on_close` to `true` instead of `false` in `config/session.php` file?

It has clearly said in the documentation on that file:

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Session Lifetime
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
 | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
 | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
 |
 */

 'lifetime' => 120,

 'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Setting `expire_on_close` to `true` will expire the session on the browser close and will automatically log out the user.

Comment: Thanks @Saiyan. I tried it also. But it is not working for chrome. That why I was usgin javascript.